# Hibernate @ElementCollection Map with @Audited create duplicate key violation on update

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-envers

I have a problem with hibernate mappings in conjunction with auditing.
My java class with mapping:

```
@Entiy
@Audited
@Table(name = "farm_detail")
public class FarmDetail {
   @Id
   private Long id;

    @ElementCollection
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "field_id")
    @Column(name = "remark")
    @CollectionTable(name = "farm_detail_remark", joinColumns =    @JoinColumn(name = "farm_detail_id"))
    private Map<String, String> fieldRemarks = new HashMap<>();
   // Getter, Setter, etc
}
```

The sql definition of the `farm_detail_remark` and `farm_detial_remark_aud` tables:

```
db=# \d farm_detail_remark
          Table "public.farm_detail_remark"
     Column     |          Type          | Modifiers 
----------------+------------------------+-----------
 farm_detail_id | bigint                 | not null
 field_id       | character varying(255) | not null
 remark         | character varying      | not null
Indexes:
    "farm_detail_remark_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (farm_detail_id, field_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "farm_detail_remark_farm_detail_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (farm_detail_id) REFERENCES farm_detail(id)

db=# \d farm_detail_remark_aud
        Table "public.farm_detail_remark_aud"
     Column     |          Type          | Modifiers 
----------------+------------------------+-----------
 rev            | integer                | not null
 revtype        | smallint               | 
 farm_detail_id | bigint                 | not null
 field_id       | character varying(255) | not null
 remark         | character varying      | 
Indexes:
    "farm_detail_remark_aud_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (rev, farm_detail_id, field_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "farm_detail_remark_aud_rev_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (rev) REFERENCES revinfo(rev)
```

If I want to update any entry of the `fieldRemarks` set I get a duplicate key error on the `farm_detail_remark_aud` table. By turning on the sql logging I found out that hibernate tries to insert two entries in the aud table:

```
Hibernate: 
    /* insert farm_detail_remark_AUD
        */ insert 
        into
            farm_detail_remark_aud
            (revtype, rev, farm_detail_id, remark, field_id) 
        values
            (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
21:20:58.188 [main] TRACE o.h.t.d.s.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [0]
21:20:58.188 [main] TRACE o.h.t.d.s.BasicBinder - binding parameter [2] as [INTEGER] - [1057]
21:20:58.188 [main] TRACE o.h.t.d.s.BasicBinder - binding parameter [3] as [BIGINT] - [110]
21:20:58.188 [main] TRACE o.h.t.d.s.BasicBinder - binding parameter [4] as [VARCHAR] - [Old remark]
21:20:58.188 [main] TRACE o.h.t.d.s.BasicBinder - binding parameter [5] as [VARCHAR] - [152]
```

and (only param binding here):

```
21:20:58.193 [main] TRACE o.h.t.d.s.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [2]
21:20:58.194 [main] TRACE o.h.t.d.s.BasicBinder - binding parameter [2] as [INTEGER] - [1057]
21:20:58.194 [main] TRACE o.h.t.d.s.BasicBinder - binding parameter [3] as [BIGINT] - [110]
21:20:58.194 [main] TRACE o.h.t.d.s.BasicBinder - binding parameter [4] as [VARCHAR] - [new remark]
21:20:58.194 [main] TRACE o.h.t.d.s.BasicBinder - binding parameter [5] as [VARCHAR] - [152]
```

Is there a way to solve this, without creating an extra entity for the remarks?

I'm using hibernate 5.0.12 shipped with spring boot 1.5.7. The database is postgresql 9.5.6.

Comment: So you're essentially updating the map's value by key within a transaction, resulting a REVTYPE=2 (DEL) related to the map key's old value and a REVTYPE=0 (ADD) related to the map key's new value.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this both against 5.0.12 and 5.2.10 and in both cases the table schema generated for your mapping differs from what you provided.  Is it possible this is legacy application that you've upgraded Hibernate within recently?

For example, on H2 the table created in my test shows the following:

```
create table farm_detail_remark_AUD (
  REV integer not null, 
  field_detail_id integer not null, 
  remark varchar(255) not null, 
  field_id varchar(255) not null, 
  REVTYPE tinyint, 
  primary key (REV, field_detail_id, remark, field_id)
)
```

Therefore for your scenario, no duplicate primary keys can be generated because the `remark` column is included as part of the primary key index which avoids the problem you're facing.

Comment: it's not legacy, but I don't let hibernate generate the database schema. But this is a good tip to let hibernate do it if you get lost. I will later check what hibernate-envers returns on such "duplicate" entries per revision. Do you know where this is documented?

Comment: We don't have any specific place that describes or documents what the schema will be based on a given mapping.  What we have often relied upon is `hibernate-tools` where users invoke it to generate a schema script and they either elect to run parts of it or at a minimum verify what they've created manually is right.

Comment: Another option is to spin up your application against a dummy database or a H2 instance with your entity mappings and look at the logs to see the DDL statements that get executed as an alternative.